# Using Express server with AngularJS scaffolded by Yeoman generator

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm trying to use ExpressJS with the scaffolded version of Angular that is installed by the [AngularJS](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) Yeoman generator. I'd prefer to use the scaffolded version created by the Yeoman Team rather than use the [angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) or [express](https://github.com/petecoop/generator-express) versions. So I manually installed Express JS in a server folder within my project.

```
-app //Angular files are here
-server //Node JS files are here
```

I think the connect server is currently being used instead of Express. Is there a way to change the grunt file to require Express instead?

I think this is the relevant code in my gruntfile.js:

```
// The actual grunt server settings
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect().use(
            '/app/styles',
            connect.static('./app/styles')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Configuration**

Yeoman generated projects can be further tweaked according to your needs by modifying project files appropriately.

You can change the app directory by adding a `appPath` property to `bower.json`. For instance, if you wanted to easily integrate with `Express.js`, you could add the following:

```
{
  "name": "yo-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  ...
  "appPath": "public"
}
```

This will cause Yeoman-generated client-side files to be placed in public.

Note that you can also achieve the same results by adding an `--appPath` option when starting generator:

`yo angular [app-name] --appPath=public`

---

I would say that you went too far with generating your project, please read carefully documentation for more details.

Comment: I'm trying to make sure that all of my communications from Angular are to my Express server and not to another server. For example, if I submit a form, I want it to be going to my Express server.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't understand how forcing the appPath to be "public" instead of "app" will affect the default server used as described in my question above.

Comment: I believe *according to docs* that `public` is a root  to `Yeoman`, from which you can configure your packages.